# Laravel Route Group for Views

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-views

I have below configuration in my Laravel /routes/web.php:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function(){
    Route::get('/', function() {
        return view('admin.login');
    });
});
```

If you observe, I have mentioned `view('admin.login')` this calls `/resources/views/admin/login.blade.php`. Which holds good as of now.

But for this Route group, I will have all my views inside `/resources/views/admin`. Thus, I do not want to use `admin` before every view-name.

Is there any possible parameter at `Route::group` level by which I can define namespace of my views, so that the Laravel searches my views in the particular directory inside `/resources/views/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem and created a helper function it worked ...
added a helpers directory under app directory `app\Helpers\functions.php`

```
function adminView($file){
   return view('foo.' . $file);
}
```

in composer.json file registered this file

```
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    },
    "files": ["app/Helpers/functions.php"]
},
```

just run `composer dump-autoload` and you can use this helper function

Answer (score 1):

You can use

`View::addNamespace('admin', '/path/to/admin/views');` or `View::addLocation('/path/to/your/admin/views');`

to specify your admin view folder in your route file.

with the first method you can use 
`return view('admin::view.name');` and with the second method you can use view name directly like `return view('view.name');`